# Using content of a variable for js function calls?

Tags: ajax

after a ajax call of a php - file i want to take a part of the feedback-result for add additional javascript code. The php file returns the code. Now i dont know how i can include it in the right way?

For better understanding

the php file returns the $result[script] = 'alert("my functions");'

the file wich controls the ajax calls looks something like that

```
url: fileurl,
           type: "post",
           data: formDetails.serialize(),
           error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                displayAjaxMessage("Sorry, there was an error");
                },
               success: function (result) {

var res = $.parseJSON(result);

//Here should be the scriptcode from the variable
$res.script;
}
```

I want to do it, beacause i think i have to redeclare some function for example plugins like bootstrap-switch, datepicker etc.

They wont work after submit the form, so i think i must inlcude the JS-Code again?

Answer (score 0):

With

```
eval(res.script);
```

It works.

Comment: it was the complete answer, more i dont need :-)